# Is it possible to inset both faces either side of a mirror line together?

Tags: mirror

I have a face being mirrored with a mirror modifier. Is it possible to inset it as if I have both selected?

Comment: You mean you want to have one inset for the two (mirrored) faces? Try pressing B (boundary) when insetting.

Comment: Thanks. Does this also work for things like Alt S? Because it extrudes unevenly with a mirror